# Get all variants from multiple products

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, elementcriteriamodel, array, plugin-craftcommerce2

I need to get a list of variants from multiple products, but in a way that allows us to show the results in Craft's handy `{% paginate %}` tags.

So far we have this less-than-appealing markup:

```
{% set firstProduct  = craft.products.relatedTo(category).one() %}
{% set results = craft.variants({product: firstProduct}) %}

{% set products  = craft.products.relatedTo(category).all() %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% set results = results|merge(craft.variants({product: product})) %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, because we're using merge it's turning our `ElementCriteriaModel` into an `Array`. Is there a way to use the `{{ craft.variants({product: product}) }}` tag and pass it multiple products?

(Craft3 and Commerce2)

Thanks

EDIT: Final markup that ended up working:

```
{# All products within this category #}
{% set products = craft.products.relatedTo(category).all() %}

{# Empty variant id array #}
{% set variantIds = [] %}

{# Populating variant id array #}
{% for product in products %}
    {% set variantIds = variantIds|merge(craft.variants({product: product}).ids()) %}
{% endfor %}

{# Get all variants from the variant id array #}
{% set results = craft.variants.id(variantIds).orderBy('title asc') %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "variant" method can receive multiple ids using the following: `craft.variants().id([1,2,3])`.

Following that, you can easily populate an array while looping through your (specific) products, and then use that array to fetch the variants.

[Official documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/dev/element-queries/variant-queries.html#id)

Comment: This helped me understand it. Thanks! See my answer for the final markup. :)